# how to make css contents like boxes, text as center?

Tags: php, css, html

i have just started css tutorial, so i don't have much idea about css. here i am posting the css code. Can you please tell me how to make whole contents center in the browser. Also I am including a screen shot of the output......

[image]

```
body {
background:#E9E9E9;


}

#formWrap {
width:720px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-right:30px;
background:#FFF;

border:1px solid #F1F1F1;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #999;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #999;
padding:16px 10px 40px;
}

#formWrap #form {
border-top: 1px solid #EEE;
width: auto;
}
#formWrap #form .row {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #EEE;
display: block;
line-height: 38px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 24px 0px;
width: 100%;
}
#formWrap #form .row .label {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width: 180px;
padding-right: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
#formWrap #form .row .input {
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
font-style: italic;
width: auto;
}

.detail{
width: 260px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 7px 8px;
margin: 0;
}

.mess {
width: 450px;
height: 250px;
max-width: 450px;
overflow: auto;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
padding: 7px 8px;
line-height: 1em;
margin: 0;
}

#formWrap #form .row .context {
color: #999;
font-size: 11px;
font-style: italic;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width: 200px;
float: left;
}


#formWrap #form .submit {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 25px;

color: #000;
font-size: 16px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999;

}
```

Comment: please also add the markup of the page or use http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Well, at least looking at the tabs the OP has open we can’t say he didn’t search first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `#formwrap` is the main container(white one and outermost), just do -

```
#formwrap{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the this line on the element you want to center:

```
#formWrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What this does is that it sets the top and bottom magin of the element to 0 and the left and right margin will be flaxable. The above is like doing

```
#formWrap {
   margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

The parameters are: *top right bottom left*. So if you set the top and right value as shown above he the browser will give those values to the bottom and left masgins. If you only set one value like:

```
#formWrap {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Then all four sides will get that value.

But back to your question ... You also have to make sure that the element that is wrapping that element you want to center is the full width of what you want center against. If not it will not do anything. Because it will center against its parent element and not e.g. the with of the screen.